# SQL Query, Trying to improve efficiency (Oracle DBMS)

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, database

For the following tables (I've used ** to indicate the parts of the primary keys)

```
Team (*tid*, name)
Game (*gid*, tid, name, year)
Member (*mid*, name)
MemberOf (*mid*, *tid*, startyear, endyear, position)
```

I need to
Show The History of each Striker (position)
If startyear is NULL use the year from the earliest game for that player for that team
Result: Striker Name, Team Name, Start Year, End Year
Sorted by the Strikers name, then the start year

Whilst I have a solution I dont think it very efficient
The Execution plan on infers a node cost of 28.
Was Hoping for improvement suggestions and explanations?

Comment: Have you tried UNION ALL? Those look like mutually exclusive queries to me and UNION ALL doesn't try to filter out duplicates. Of course make sure that UNION ALL returns exactly the same results.

Comment: I don't see any fields that would enable me to find the year of the earliest game for a specific team.  Does your game table have a date field that you are not displaying?

Comment: Thanks HLGEM, The ALL saved one on the Node Cost
Dan, Your right, I missed it! Edited to add in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with one query, using `left outer join` and `coalesce` (if I have the logic correct):

```
SELECT Striker_Name, Team_Name, coalesce(MO.STARTYEAR, g.start_year), MO.ENDYEAR
FROM (SELECT NAME AS Striker_Name, MID
      FROM MEMBER
      ) ME JOIN
      (SELECT MID, TID, STARTYEAR AS Start_Year, ENDYEAR AS End_Year
       FROM MEMBEROF
       WHERE POSITION = 'striker'
      ) MO ON ME.MID = MO.MID left outer JOIN
      (SELECT NAME AS Team_Name, TID
       FROM TEAM
      ) T
      ON MO.TID = T.TID left outer JOIN
      (SELECT GID, MIN(GAME.YEAR) AS Start_Year FROM GAME GROUP BY TID
      ) G
      ON G.TID = MO.TID
ORDER BY Striker_Name, Start_Year
```

You seem to be filling in the start year from the earliest game.  Just do the join and decide in the `select` which one to use.

Comment: Thanks, it appears to be close to what I am after, however this seems to only return the results where STARTYEAR is NULL?

Comment: @user2036256 . . . I think I missed one of the joins.  They should all be left outer joins.

Comment: The only other join is the first one. Changing it to a left outer just causes all Members to be listed!

Comment: @user2036256 . . . Duh.  That condition was in the subquery.  Silly mistake.  The whole purpose of using one query was to get rid of that condition (as I just did).

Comment: Ahh, crap, Can't believe I didnt spot that either.
Thanks! Havn't seen coalesce before. I think i need to take a few more sql tutorials